# setting h:selectBooleanCheckbox value to false prevents commandButton oncomplete from being invoked

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml, richfaces

I am new to JSF and am working with an `rich:extendedDataTable` where one of the columns has an `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` as the header for select all purposes.

At the bottom of the table there is a `a4j:commandButton` (delete selected button) with an `oncomplete` action to launch a `rich:popupPanel` (confirm delete panel).

This all works fine, but when the table is refreshed, the select all checkbox remains checked after a delete is performed. In an effort to have it default to false when the table has been refreshed after a delete, I tried adding `value="#{false}"` to the checkbox. The problem is, when this value is set, my commandButton's `oncomplete` no longer gets invoked and is unable to show the pop-up panel.

I don't see the connection between the two, but maybe someone has an idea? Both the commandButton and extendedDataTable are within the same `h:form` For the time being, I am having my pop-up panel appear by using `onbegin` instead.

here is the code for my select all column.:

```
<rich:column id="modSelectColId" label="Selected">
    <f:facet name="header">
       <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selectAllId" onclick="selectAll(this)" value="#{false}"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selectId" value="#{myBean.selectedMap[item]}" />
</rich:column>
```

here is the code for my command button:

```
<a4j:commandButton 
    value="Delete Selected"
    oncomplete="#{rich:component('delSelectPopupId')}.show()" />
```